# Can document.domain include port number?

Tags: javascript

I'm running the development server on `localhost:8000`. Can `document.domain` include a port number, e.g., `document.domain = 'localhost:8000'`? I seem to be getting an error saying `localhost:8000` cannot be parsed properly.

Comment: *"...seem to be..."*?

Comment: A **domain** doesn't contain a port, so...no. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `document.domain` includes only the host name.

> `document.domain`
>
> Gets/sets the domain portion of the origin of the current document, as used by the same origin policy.

[image: preview]

Alternatively, `location.port` gets you the port of the domain.

Comment: document.domain sets the domain portion used by the same origin policy. Hoe to set the port portion used by same origin policy?